# Why is only my first HTTP request running?

Tags: jmeter

I'm still pretty new to jmeter. I'm using jmeter 2.9.

I have created a thread group with two threads in it. I have set up an HTTP Request Defaults for the thread group. I have created User Parameters to define person IDs that I'm going to be working with in each thread.

I then set up two HTTP requests. One for login, one for retrieve person. For the login one, I created a regular expression extractor to extract the session key that comes back. I then supply the session key as the parameter for the retrieve person request.

I then sniffed the net traffic and started jmeter test. I wanted to make sure the session key was getting passed into the second parameter OK, but it appears to be running on the login twice and then ending. I am getting a 200 return on the HTTP packet and my jmeter test was set to continue regardless.

I believe I followed chapter 5 of the jmeter user manual to set up this test with the addition of parameters, user parameters, and the regex extractor.

Can anyone give me an idea what i might have done so that the second request never runs?

Comment: Add "View Results Tree" listener to see what jMeter is actually doing? You should also check jmeter.log to see if there are any exceptions while generating the 2nd request.

Comment: show you test plan structure in a screenshot added to your question

Comment: @Manish You helped me find the problem with my regular expression extractor. Please post as an answer so I can mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add "View Results Tree" listener to see what jMeter is actually doing? You should also check jmeter.log to see if there are any exceptions while generating the 2nd request.